# how do i configure the plank in elementary os?

Tags: plank

I recently switched to elementary OS and wanted to configure plank (or the dock, whatever it's called), but even though it is installed its not showing up in the applications menu, how do I configure it? do I need to install plank preferences through the terminal, if so could somebody tell me the command?

edit: if it's important i was pretty familiar with Ubuntu before switching s i know a little bit about gnome

Answer (score 2):

Hold control and simultaneously right-click the dock. Select preferences.

Answer (score -1):

You can type in terminal `plank --preferences` to open plank preference.