# How do I remove build-in docklets from Plank?

Tags: release-juno, plank

I found this question and decieded to try it out:
[how do i configure the plank in elementary os?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/how-do-i-configure-the-plank-in-elementary-os)

I held the **ctrl** button, right-clicked the Plank, and selected Preferences.
I then clicked Docklets.

I double-clicked **Applications** and **Desktop** and they were put on the Plank. But now I can't remove them. Double-clicking them again won't remove them. There is no **"Keep in Dock"** box to uncheck. Anybody know how I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

drag 'Desktop' icon from dock to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is to make sure your Icon are not locked.
From the Behavior tab check if they are locked, then unlock them and then  drag  icons from dock to somewhere else.